# Trying to send blank excel doc to user using Web Api / NPOI

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, npoi

It says the stream is closed. I am just trying to figure out how I send back a blank .xls file.

ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream.
System.IO.__Error.StreamIsClosed()

```
 [Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Report")]
public class ReportController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Get()
    {
        IWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        ISheet sheet1 = workbook.CreateSheet("Sheet1");

        using (var exportData = new MemoryStream())
        {
            workbook.Write(exportData);
            string saveAsFileName = string.Format("Export-{0:d}.xlsx", DateTime.Now).Replace("/", "-");
            byte[] bytes = exportData.ToArray();
            return File(exportData, "application/vnd.ms-excel", saveAsFileName);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a byte array from the `MemoryStream` but you are not sending it to the `File` method.  So the `File` method is trying to access the stream, but it is already closed by that point.

Change this line:

```
return File(exportData, "application/vnd.ms-excel", saveAsFileName);
```

To this:

```
return File(bytes, "application/vnd.ms-excel", saveAsFileName);
```